# SharePoint App can't Post form data to REST using Angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, rest, sharepoint

I am using angular to post form data to SharePoint's REST service, but it is not posting. I am able to "get" JSON data without issue and believe I am missing something obvious. I also don't receive an error message.

Here is sample REST data, of which I would like to create another entry in the "value" object:

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x010400AF4ACA1755AD48428EF182FA566973E6",
        "Title": "Test1",
        "Body": "<div class=\"ExternalClass5217CB82669B4C4B901FC90EF1D1734F\"><p>Test 1 body​</p></div>",
        "Expires": null,
        "RequesterId": null,
        "ManagerId": null,
        "ID": 1,
        "Modified": "2015-03-11T21:52:33Z",
        "Created": "2015-03-11T21:52:33Z",
        "AuthorId": 12,
        "EditorId": 12,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "e46af534-f488-4389-ad7e-726ed2af0d52"
    }
]
```

}

Here is my form (the controller is tied to the page via routing and is working):

```
<form name="newItem" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="createItem()" novalidate>
<fieldset>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="title">Title *</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" name="title" id="title" type="text" data-ng-model="itemtitle" placeholder="Add your title (Limited to 70 characters)" data-ng-maxlength="70" required>
            ({{70 - newItem.title.$viewValue.length}} Characters Remaining)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="body">Body *</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" data-ng-model="itembody" rows="4" placeholder="Add your body (Limited to 500 characters)" data-ng-maxlength="500" required> </textarea>
            Your summary will be displayed as follows ({{500 - newItem.body.$viewValue.length}} Characters Remaining):<br /> {{itembody}}

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="newItem.$invalid">Submit</button>
            <p data-ng-show="newItem.$invalid" class="help-block validsubmit">The submit button will become "active" once all fields are properly filled out.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Here is my controller:

```
// Add new item
appControllers.controller('appItemPostCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'appItems', function ($scope, $location, appItems) {

var itemEntry = new appItems;

$scope.createItem = function () {

    itemEntry.Title = $scope.itemtitle;
    itemEntry.value.$save();
    $location.path('/');
}

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $location.path('/');
}

}]);
```

Here is my service (I wonder if I need the "save"):

```
appServices.factory('appItems', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Todo Task List')/Items", {},
    {
        'query': { method: "GET", isArray: false, headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'}},
        'update': { method: 'PATCH', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' } },
        'save': { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() } },
    }
    );
}]);
```

EDIT: I have added "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() header to my POST method, but it is still not working

Comment: Update: In testing, I am not getting an error because the function is not getting called, once I click the button it is re-routing. I am using hashbang mode. How do I get the button to work instead of routing?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting pattern for using `$resource`, I haven't see it used like that before. I think the reason you can call `POST` is because you can't use `$save` on items not returned as a result of `get()`.

Try:

`appItems.save({title: $scope.itemtitle})`

Comment: Where would I use the appItems.save? Is it better to get items and then perform a save?

Comment: You can call `appItems.save()` in the `$scope.createItem()` method

Comment: No such luck. I updated my code to:  var itemEntry = new appItems;     $scope.createItem = function () {itemEntry.Title = $scope.itemtitle;       appItems.save();}

What is the "normal" way of doing this?

Comment: You would need to get all the information before saving it, are you trying to update as well?

Comment: I don't think the code you have in the comments will work, try the following:

` $scope.createItem = function () {
appItems.save({title: $scope.itemtitle});
}`

Comment: No such luck. I wonder if it has to do with the JSON format with the "value" object. Mixing SharePoint and Angular has been some "work".

Comment: Perhaps. Since I am unfamiliar with SharePoint and its API, this is all I can suggest. Hopefully someone more knowledgable has a solution for you.

Comment: It at least rules out other aspects as the code above works in pure angular apps I have built.